# List VNC error status in next column (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

This is the VBA script I am using to launch VNC for the active cell:

```
Sub RunVNC()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = "C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe " & ActiveCell.Value
    RetVal = Shell(txt)
End Sub
```

I want to have it list the error status 1 column to the right of the selected cell.

It would be nice to also have it launch VNC for the entire column (starting from row 3) instead of only the selected cell. Having a hard time putting this together - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please expand. In what way are you "having a hard time"? What happened? What did you see that you didn't want to see? What didn't you see that you wanted to see? What did you try in order to resolve it? What research material led you to this point? Y'know, the nitty-gritty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your basic process actually works:

```
Sub RunVNC()
    Dim txt As String, c As Range

    For Each c in ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A100").cells 'for example
        If len(c.value)>0 Then
            txt = "C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe " & c.Value
            c.offset(0, 1).Value = Shell(txt)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```